# ObservableCollection update after binding

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

I have an `ObservbleCollection` with binding to listbox. After I put the collection as ItemsSource of the list, I cannot update my collection. If I update it, the program close (without any crash).

**The Code:**
I have the class:

```
class MyFile
{
    String FileName {get; set;}
    ImageSource Ico {get; set;}
}
```

Then run the code in the constractor (after InitializeComponents)

```
ObservableCollection<MyFile> filesList = new ObservableCollection<MyFile>();
filesList.Add(new MyFile { Name = "bar.doc", Ico = null } // Work Fine
filesList.Add(new MyFile { Name = "foo.txt", Ico = null } // Work Fine
files.ItemsSource = filesList; 
filesList.Add(new MyFile { Name = "try.txt", Ico = null } // EXIT FROM PROGRAM
```

What's wrong in my program?

**Edit**
Just tested it with null instead GetIcon

Comment: Can you show the `GetIcon` method?

Comment: It very complicated, I got it from the internet. If I will put null instead the program act the same

Comment: Thats weird, What is the type of `files`?

Comment: Just `ListBox` with templates

Comment: There's no binding action in your code!!! Read the documentation, especially BASIC samples, and you'll get how to do it. With this code you're 180 degrees away from the right direction!!!

Comment: The binding is on the XAML file, and this code is just a test that I ran.

Comment: You code should work fine. Please post your XAML! You should also turn on the ALL exception catching in Visual Studio. Go to Debug -> Exceptions-> Add check the all checkboxes in the line: Common-Language runtime exceptions

Comment: If binding is on the XAML what does "files.ItemsSource = filesList;" stand there for? I repeat again read the docs and see the samples: to bind objects you should use DependencyPropertyes or implement INotyfyPropertyChangend. But, once more, read the docs!!!! At least the chapter regarding data binding, you're falling on the really basic stuff.

Comment: Can I create this list in the XAML?

Comment: You could do anything when you know how to do it. And to know how to do it, you should study!! What would it take to you to google for a "observablecollection wpf binding sample" and then get something like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748365.aspx

Comment: Hmm, What is so bad with my code? I just create the list in the code and set it as ItemsSource... What so bad with it?

Comment: ItemsSource should not be set, but Binded to use bindings. I just put an answer to show it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx)'s mission is to announce changes (add, remove, ...) to the listener. So nothing is wrong with `ObservableCollection` and binding it as the `ItemsSource` of the ListBox, will not make it uneditable. It must be something wrong with the `GetIcon` method (e.g. trying to reopen the same image which was not close properly)

To see if this idea is correct try this:

```
ObservableCollection<MyFile> filesList = new ObservableCollection<MyFile>();
filesList.Add(new MyFile { Name = "bar.doc", Ico = GetIcon(".doc") }
//filesList.Add(new MyFile { Name = "foo.txt", Ico = GetIcon(".txt") } // Comment this line
files.ItemsSource = filesList; 
filesList.Add(new MyFile { Name = "try.txt", Ico = GetIcon(".txt") }
```

If you want to see the bug. I suggest you copy those lines in a click event of a button (and not in the constructor) then run your application.

Comment: Yea, I have item template of image and label.

Comment: Remove these lines from constructor and put them into a `Click` event of a button and run the app. Then click that button. This way you can see what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small sample on binding an ObservableCollection using DependencyPropery. I wish it helps you on how to do DataBinding in this way.

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

        x:Name="MyWindow"

        Title="MainWindow">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyList, ElementName=MyWindow, Mode=TwoWay}">
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code Behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Threading;

using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Logica di interazione per MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MyListProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyList", typeof(ObservableCollection<string>), typeof(MainWindow));

        public ObservableCollection<string> MyList
        {
            get
            {
                return (ObservableCollection<string>)GetValue(MyListProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(MyListProperty, value);
            }
        }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MyList = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "a", "b" };
            MyList.Add("c");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. My real `ObservableCollection` is in another class called `FilesManager` that manage all the files and it singleton class. I still prefer my way, but thanks.

Comment: Please let me know how you'll get out from this problem without using binding properly. It's quite interesting to see a man challenging the WPF Framework.